# Zip file Attachment in mail Issue

Tags: php, email-attachments, php-ziparchive

I am trying to send mail with zip attachment (containing CSV file) using phpMailer.

But when i execute I’m getting zip file in specified location and in mail but in both I can’t extract the CSV file it says CRC failed, file is corrupted.

Can anyone tell me the solution?

```
<?php

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$now = new DateTime();

$info = pathinfo($filename);
$name = $info['filename'];
$ext = $info['extension'];

$time = "download.zip";
$pathto = "images/importcsv/download.zip";
$res = $zip->open($pathto, ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($res == true) {
    $zip->addFile($filename, substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '/') + 1));
}

$zip->close();

yii::import('application.extensions.smtpmail.PHPMailer');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->Host = $dmmodel->host;
$mail->Username = $dmmodel->username;
$mail->Password = $dmmodel->password;
$mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
$mail->Port = $dmmodel->port;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = ($dmmodel->smtp_enableSSL == 1 ? 'ssl' : ($dmmodel->smtp_enableSSL == 2 ? 'tls' : ''));

$mail->From = $dmmodel->email_from;
$mail->FromName = $dmmodel->name_from;

$mail->Subject = "Cron Export CSV";
$mail->MsgHTML("Cron Export CSV");
$mail->AddAddress($dmmodel->default_TO, "");
$mail->AddAttachment("images/importcsv/download.zip", "download.zip");
if (!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: is `images/importcsv/download.zip` already corruped on the server or just in the mail ?

Comment: corrupted on the server itslef

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/zip.constants.php here are the zip error flags (which are just integers). If you check with `$res == true` it will be true for any integer != 0; so you should check with `$res === true` or if its an int, check which error it corresponds to